# Any big differences between the Core i7 940 and 950?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7

It seems the only difference between the Intel Core i7 940 and 950 is a minor clock speed increase, is there anything else that has been changed? I've read the white papers on both processors and they seem almost identical, but the 940 is being discontinued. Was it only discontinued because the slightly faster 950 was released? There seems to be a $100 price difference for me.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be that different. The price difference could be down to a new *vs* old stock thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a big difference just few are listed below:

#### Intel® Core™ i7-940 Processor

> Clock Speed                               2.93 GHz
>   Max Turbo Frequency               3.2 GHz
>   Intel® Smart Cache                    8 MB
>   Bus/Core Ratio                          22

#### Intel® Core™ i7-950 Processor

> Clock Speed                                3.06 GHz
>   Max Turbo Frequency                3.33 GHz
>   Intel® Smart Cache                     8 MB
>   Bus/Core Ratio                          23

Specs for [Intel® Core™ i7-940 Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/37148/Intel-Core-i7-940-Processor-(8M-Cache-2_93-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI)) & specs for [Intel® Core™ i7-950 Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/37150/Intel-Core-i7-950-Processor-(8M-Cache-3_06-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI)).

Answer (score 0):

If they have the same stepping, they would actually be the same thing, just rated differently depending on unit quality.